# How to find your way in Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

Is there a way to set waypoints so that you can see which direction you should go towards? I know for some challenges / objectives you get directions, but when I set a custom waypoint on the map or set it on a challenge, nothing happens. Am I doing something wrong?

I really need to find my way towards locations, even bringing the map up takes time (I have to press select, then navigate through 2 other tabs to get to the map) it's getting really annoying.

Answer (score 10):

To pull up the map, press <kbd>Back</kbd>/<kbd>Select</kbd> to bring up the map, then you can use <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd>/<kbd>△</kbd> to set and clear objectives. Pressing <kbd>Ⓨ</kbd>/<kbd>△</kbd> will set a waypoint/objective, then you can press it again to clear it and return to the story objective. The compass at the top of the screen (not visible in detective/thief modes) will also show your waypoint/objective.

Comment: Note also that anytime you do this, you get a big Batsignal symbol in the sky for you to easily follow as well! It will have arrows from it going down to the ground on the location you set. I actually didn't realize this until a few hours in.

Comment: You also don't have to set a waypoint at an objective - a waypoint can be set anywhere on the map.

Comment: For completion, note that you also get an indicator on your compass at the top of the screen. From what I recall the indicator for custom waypoints is always a bat signal

Comment: Thanks everyone, specially @FallenAngelEyes that's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @David If the answer satisfies your question, could you please click on the checkmark next to it to mark it as the accepted answer? :)